# Converting unicode string to hexadecimal representation

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I want to convert unicode string to its hexadecimal representation. 
For example, `u'\u041a\u0418\u0421\u0410'` should be converted to `"\xD0\x9A\xD0\x98\xD0\xA1\xD0\x90"`. I tried the code below (python 2.7):

```
unicode_username.encode("utf-8").encode("hex")
```

However, I get a string:

```
'd09ad098d0a1d090'
```

Any suggestions how I can get `\xD0\x9A\xD0\x98\xD0\xA1\xD0\x90`?

Comment: Don't do the second encode. `unicode_username.encode("utf-8")` -> `'\xd0\x9a\xd0\x98\xd0\xa1\xd0\x90'`.

Comment: The second encode doesn't work with Python3, because the bytes object returned by the first encode doesn't have any `.encode()` method. Use `unicode_username.encode('utf-8').hex()` to get a text string of hex ASCII.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do `string.encode('utf-8')`, it changes to hex notation.

But if you print it, you will get original unicode string.

If you want the hex notation you can get it like this with `repr()` function:

```
>>> print u'\u041a\u0418\u0421\u0410'.encode('utf-8')
КИСА
>>> print repr(u'\u041a\u0418\u0421\u0410'.encode('utf-8'))
'\xd0\x9a\xd0\x98\xd0\xa1\xd0\x90'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try:

```
print "hex_signature :  ",'\\X'.join(x.encode("hex") for x in signature)
```

The join function is used with the separator '\X' so that for each byte to hex conversion the \X is inserted. The join function is done for each byte of the variable signature in a loop. Everything is joined/concatenated and printed.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.