# Python - \xb in strings

Tags: python

I am quite new in Python and here in this code, I am trying to write a code that reads a text file containing list of cities and their respective longitudes and latitudes, and then returns them as a dictionary containing the list of the cities including their longitudes and latitudes.

The text file looks like this:

```
Name: Koln Latitude: 4° 45' N Longitude: 2° 55' W
Name: Amersfoort Latitude: 1° 23' N Longitude: 2° 23' E
```

And my code is like this:

```
import re

def controller(filename):
    citydict = {}
    filevar = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in filevar:
        city = delegate(line)
        citydict[city[0]] = city
    filevar.close()
    return citydict

def delegate(ln):
    pattern = "Name: (.*) Latitude: (.*)? (.*)' (.) Longitude: (.*)? (.*)' (.)"
    matcher = re.compile(pattern)
    match = matcher.search(ln)
    name = match.group(1)
    latitude = match.group(2), match.group(3), match.group(4)
    longitude = match.group(5), match.group(6), match.group(7)
    city = (name, latitude, longitude)
    return city

print controller('cities.txt')
```

The code runs well but somehow, the got weird output like 2\xb in it. Anyone know what that means and how to fix them?

```
{'Koln': ('Koln', ('4\xb0', '45', 'N'), ('2\xb0', '55', 'W')), 'Amersfoort': ('Amersfoort', ('1\xb0', '23', 'N'), ('2\xb0', '23', 'E'))}
```

Comment: It's probably the degree character.

Comment: It is just the [hex encoding of unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420622/converting-unicode-string-to-hexadecimal-representation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression has a mistake. The `?` says to match the previous expression, `(.*)`, zero or one time(s).

```
(.*)?
```

If the degree character is always there, you can do this:

```
(.*).
```

Comment: Solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it correspond to the  `°` in unicode :

```
>>> print u'\xb0'
°
```